# click on image shows image and content in popup

Tags: wordpress, popup

I have a wordpress site and I'm displaying images on a page. 
When you click on an image I would like a popup to show the image and content associated with the image. 
Each image and content is a post. 
I'm trying to use the code:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
$post = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
$title = $post['post_title'];
```

to get the title of the content. 
Then I need to use jquery so when you click the image the title (and also the content) show up.
In which file do I put the jquery code? 
How do I link the image so onclick() it shows the popup?

Comment: you need to try something yourself here....you could create a hidden div with the information and use jquery to show the content when clicked and something like a delay to close the window. Either that or use ajax to fetch the content.

Comment: do you have an example of how I can use jquery to show content when clicked? I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the bottom of your template.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // wait until all document html loaded 

    jQuery('.unhide').click(function(){ // attach a function to elements with the class "unhide"
       jQuery(this).closest('.holder').find('.hidden').show(); // Look for the closest parent of this item with the class "holder" and find the hidden div, show it
       jQuery(this).closest('.holder').find('.hidden').delay( 800 ).hide(1000); // find the same element and close after delay, take 1000 ms to close. 
    });

 });
 </script>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hrcsguu/1/

Simple example that assumes the parent item contains the hidden content and a button to use as the click event. http://api.jquery.com/ has examples for every function. All you need to know beyond this is use script tags for js and use jQuery instead of the $ symbol used.